# UPDATE table whith specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables - `products`  and `product_categories`.

These tables JOIN ON `products`.`product_id` = `product_categories`.`product_id` .

I want to UPDATE field `published` in table `products` which have condition `product_categories.product_categories` = 100 .

Comment: bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories doesn't have a column named bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE bjvui_virtuemart_products as prod
  INNER JOIN bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories as cat
  ON prod.virtuemart_product_id =cat.virtuemart_product_id
SET prod.published ={value}
WHERE cat.virtuemart_category_id=100
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'cat.bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories' in 'where clause'

Comment: are you sure that the field in the where clause is 'bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories', that is the name of the table

Comment: bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories is the name of the table, you need to say us what is the field of the table that must have value to "100"

Comment: yes, you right. My mistace. Must be `bjvui_virtuemart_categories`.`virtuemart_category_id` = 100;

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer with the correct field, try now the new query

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE with JOIN

```
UPDATE TABLEA a 
JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
WHERE a.someColumn = [some_value]
```

For your case

```
UPDATE bjvui_virtuemart_products AS p
INNER JOIN bjvui_virtuemart_product_categories AS c ON 
p.virtuemart_product_id = c.virtuemart_product_id
SET p.published = "your_value"
WHERE c.virtuemart_category_id = 100;
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.